# the activity restarts when the phones View Mode is changed

Tags: android

In my application while playing a video if i change the phone's mode the video does not continue to play but it starts from the beginning. all i understand is the activity is recreated when the mode is changed,how do i fix this i have no idea please someone help me fix this.
 thanks in advance

Comment: look for a parameter name onconfigchange

Comment: could you please explain in detail as i am new to android

Comment: in AndroidManifest, under activty set onconfigchange property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this line in your AndroidManifest file to your activity tag, by this your activity won't get re-started.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Comment: why do we need to add keyboardhidden property

Comment: Checkout this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Doing this will not stop orientation.It is used to get orientation change event in the activity..

Comment: Yes, but it will stop the re-creation of Activity. You can try it out.

Comment: @lalit have tryed your solution and it completely works.. and also the documentation you given in link is saying the same thing...so +1 for that. keep up the good work.

Comment: @VineetShukla no problem buddy your solution is also a nice way that I learnt a new thing +1 for that. :)

Comment: Welcome and would like to learn more from your answer. keep it up.

Answer (score 4):

when your activity restarts save the current postion of the video thru this method:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    int videoPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("POSITION", videoPosition);
    return data;
}
```

and on `onCreate()` method retrieve this value like this:

```
final Bundle data = (Bundle) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

// The activity is starting for the first time...
if (data == null) {
   // start your video for the first time here..
} else {
    // Resume your video from where it was left..
    int videoPosition = data.getInt("POSITION");
// start your video from videoposition....          
}
```